# Intercepting and postprocessing all audio streams on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, audio, intercept

I would like to know is there any way I create an application which can intercept all the audio that is being played back on the computer, so I can process the audio (apply some effect) and then pass it further to the Windows audio subsystem?

I just had a glimpse in Vista/7 WASAPI, there is this sAPO:
http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/device/audio/sysfx.mspx
but it seems that I cannot create my sAPO and install it anywhere I like - I need a WHQL drivers for this.

Is there any universal way to do that?
I have an experience with DirectSound but I haven't seen any useful info about intercepting the audio streams.

Answer (score 2):

If you're loading a custom sAPO, you're globally affecting the sound for a system.  This is going to require signing.  [From this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff538609%28v=VS.85%29.aspx):

> The audio engine does not load
>   unsigned sAPOs into the audio
>   processing graph. So while you are
>   testing your sAPO, you must disable
>   the protected process for Audiodg.exe.
>   To disable the protected process, set
>   the value of the
>   DisableProtectedAudioDG registry key
>   to '1'.